# Pandas dataframe group by 10 min intervals with different actions on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, pandas-resample

I have a pandas dataframe which includes a timestamp and 71 other columns, something like this:

```
              timestamp           |close_price|highest_price|volume| ...
              2018-09-29 00:00:20 |1809       |1811         |  ... |
              2018-09-29 00:00:34 |1823       |1832         |
              2018-09-29 00:00:59 |1832       |1863         |
              2018-09-29 00:01:09 |1800       |1802         |
              2018-09-29 00:01:28 |1832       |1845         |
              .
              .
              .
```

I want to put the data into 10 min intervals and I want to do separate operations on each column, for example I want the 10 min intervals of `close_price` column to show the `last` value of the corresponding range in the real table, or for the `highest_price` column, I want the `max` value of the corresponding range, or for `volume` I want the `mean` of the values in that range. I already tried

```
dataTable = datefram.resample("10min").agg({'first_price':'first',
                                       'close_price':'last',
                                       'highest_price': 'max',
                                       'volume':'mean', 
                                        #other attributes...
                                        })
```

but the result seems to be incorrect.
Is there any other ways to do what I want to do?
I will appreciate any comments or thoughts.

Note that there is no specific pattern in timestamp values. In 1 minute, we can have 0 to 60 rows.

Comment: How are the results incorrect? It looks like you're on the right track based on this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68229747/resample-dataframe-calculate-min-max-and-first-and-last-of-different-columns-w

Comment: @ChrisSears thank you for your comment, Yeah it looks to be ok but the problem is that it I have 12808 rows in the input and 13207 rows in output.

Comment: Does your data span multiple days? If so, `resample()` could be creating output rows for overnight periods where you don't have any data points, leading to a lot of `NaN` values.

Comment: @ChrisSears OH, yes, you are right. I have so many ```nan``` values. could you please consider writing a simple answer so I can up-vote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct. The
 `dataframe.resample("10min").agg()` does the calculations for you.
You might get more outputs than what you expect and that is because of this: `resample` method continuously adds 10 minutes to the time and does the calculations that you asked. But if there was no data in any of the `10 min` intervals, it creates a `NULL` row. Maybe your data is not continuous and causes this `Null` rows.

You can simply delete the `NULL` rows by using `dataframe.dropna()`

Answer (score 1):

If your data spans multiple days or periods where you don't have any data points, calling `resample()` can result in lots of additional rows with `NaN` values. I think your code is actually correct, you just got the wrong impression from seeing all the extra rows.

Comment: Thank you so much